# Codeigniter - forms

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and try to understand how to create forms. I searched both on the Net and stackopverflow but did not reach anything.

What i want is to create forms with helpers.
In order to do that in my controller create a function, named formElements() and the code is

```
public function formElements()
        {
            $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        }
```

and in kayit.php

i try to create some html elements

```
<?=form_open('kayit/formElements')?>
    <?=form_fieldset('Login Form')?>

        <div class="textfield">
            <?=form_label('username', 'user_name')?>
            <?=form_input('user_name')?>
        </div>

        <div class="textfield">
            <?=form_label('password', 'user_pass')?>
            <?=form_password('user_pass')?>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <?=form_submit('login', 'Login')?>
        </div>

    <?=form_fieldset_close()?>
<?=form_close();?>
```

However i take the error : **Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pasaj\application\views\kayit.php on line 220**

why?

Answer (score 5):

You can also include the form helper in ./application/config/autoload.php file

`$autoload['helper'] = array('form');`

Answer (score 3):

You can include the form helper in your Controller's constructor function, like:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

And it should work fine in view.
Ref: [Form Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)
Hope it helps

Comment: Sidenote @Mert METIN if you intend to use the form_validation library, you don't need to load form helper again as it is already "included"